# How to automatically create an html form from an pydantic model?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Is there a way to create an Html form from a pydantic model?

Let's start with an easy example.
I have a model `User`:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str = 'Jane Doe'
```

and some magic function that transforms the `User` model into the following form:

```
<form>
  <label for="id">ID:</label><br>
  <input type="number" id="id" name="id"><br>
  <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</form>
```

Of course, this can be arbitrarily complex e.g. when your model has `List`s which might be a Dropdown selection field.

So I'm interested if this is somehow already possible? I would be using this in the context of FastAPI.

Comment: I suppose that no such method exists. Maybe there's a 3rd party library, but writing such a method by yourself shouldn't be so complicated either, I suppose: Iterate over the non-private members of the class, and add an HTML string according to their type and properties. Finally, join the HTML strings to produce a HTML snippet.

Comment: Piccolo Admin supports pydantic models in their form config object: https://piccolo-orm.com/blog/easy-forms-using-pydantic-and-piccolo-admin/ - reforms is also an option, although currently unmaintained: https://github.com/boardpack/reforms

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a form from Pydantic's schema output.
There are a few options, [jsonforms](https://jsonforms.io/) seems to be best.

First generate json-schema from your model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class MyClass(BaseModel):
  name: str 
  # ... etc... 

json_schema = MyClass.schema()
```

This outputs:

```
# -> {'title': 'MyClass', 'type': 'object', 'properties': {'name': {'title': 
# -> 'Name', #'type': 'string'}}, 'required': ["name"]}
```

You can use this output to automatically make a form with jsonforms (see [example on homepage](https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform)) it handles nested lists and objects fine and has lots of validation options on the front-end

For a more back-end solution you could use something like django forms, and there's a library for using jsonforms with django forms [django-jsonforms](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonforms/) it provides a `JSONSchemaField` that can be used like this:

```
class CustomForm(Form):    
    first_name = JSONSchemaField(schema = schema_from_above)
```

This can be used with a template engine like Jinja as the other answer points out...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one I created that works out of the box

```
class PydanticForm(forms.Form):
  """
  USAGE:
  form = PydanticForm(schema=PydanticModel.model_json_schema())
  --> <PydanticForm bound=False, valid=Unknown, fields=(f1;f2;f3;f4;...)>

  print(form.as_p())
  <p>
    <label for="id_short">Short:</label>
    <input type="text" name="short" maxlength="10" id="id_short">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="id_long">Long:</label>
    <input type="text" name="long" maxlength="1000" id="id_long">
  </p>
  """

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # find 'schema' and 'options' param from kwargs
    schema = kwargs.pop('schema', None)
    options = kwargs.pop('options', {})
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # if Pydantic schema provided, build a form from that schema
    if schema:
      self.build_fields_from_schema(schema=schema, options=options)

    # apply the 'form-control rounded-0' classes to every field in the form. depending onyour css
    for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
      field.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control rounded-0'}) 

  def build_fields_from_schema(self, schema, options=None):
    """
    fields = build_fields_from_schema(PydanticModel.model_json_schema())
    fields
    {
      'f1': <django.forms.fields.CharField at 0x1f37ed386d0>,
      'f2': <django.forms.fields.CharField at 0x1f37ed386a0>,
      'f3': <django.forms.fields.CharField at 0x1f37ed387c0>,
    }
    """
    properties = schema.get('properties', {})
    excluded_fields = ['uuid', 'ulid']  # if you have private fields you dont want to render
    
    for field_name, field_info in properties.items():
      if field_name in excluded_fields:
        continue

      field = self.create_form_field(field_name, field_info, options)
      if field:
        self.fields[field_name] = field

  def create_form_field(self, property_name, property_info, options_dict=None):
    """
    USAGE:
      schema = PydanticModel.model_json_schema()
      properties = schema.get('properties', {})
  
    for field_name, field_info in properties.items():
      field = create_form_field(field_name, field_info)
    """
    field_type, is_nullable, has_default, default_value, constraints = self.extract_field_metadata(property_info)
    field_options = {'required': not is_nullable and not has_default}
    field_options.update(constraints) # append extra params if found

    # Set the default value if there's a default defined in the Pydantic model
    if has_default:
      field_options['initial'] = default_value

    # If options discovered, convert field to be a choice field. No valdiation required bc we assuming the options are all good
    if property_name in options_dict:
      # Ensure the choices are in list of 2-tuples BC THAT IS HOW DJANGO WANTS IT
      choices = [(option, option) for option in options_dict[property_name]] # opt = ['i1', 'i2'] --> [('i1', 'i1'), ('i2', 'i2)]
      return self.create_choice_field(property_info, choices, field_options)
    
    if field_type in ['date', 'datetime', 'date-time']:
      return self.create_date_field(property_info, field_options)

    if field_type == 'string':
      return self.create_string_field(property_info, field_options)
        
    if field_type == 'number':
      return self.create_number_field(property_info, field_options)
    
    if field_type == 'boolean':
      return self.create_boolean_field()
    
    return None

  def extract_field_metadata(self, property_info):
    """
    class Model:
      date: Optional[Union[datetime, str]] = Field(None)

    property_info = {
      'anyOf': [{
        'format': 'date-time', 'type': 'string'}, # format can be different from type
        {'type': 'string'}, 
        {'type': 'null'},
      }], 
      'default': None, 
      'title': 'Date'
    }
    """
    # Initialize default values
    is_nullable = False
    has_default = 'default' in property_info
    default_value = property_info.get('default', None)
    field_type = None
    constraints = {} 

    # 'anyOf' is property generated by fields with input Union[[type1, type2]] or Optional[type1]
    if 'anyOf' in property_info:
      field_type, is_nullable, constraints = self.handle_anyof_structure(property_info['anyOf'])
    else:
      field_type = property_info.get('type')
      is_nullable = field_type == 'null'
    
    return field_type, is_nullable, has_default, default_value, constraints

  def create_choice_field(self, property_info, choices, options:dict):
    options = {key: value for key, value in options.items() if key in ['required', 'initial']} # take only the params required to build field
    return forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, **options)

  def create_string_field(self, property_info, options:dict):
    options = {key: value for key, value in options.items() if key in ['required', 'initial', 'min_length', 'max_length']}
    return forms.CharField(**options)

  def create_number_field(self, property_info, options:dict):
    options = {key: value for key, value in options.items() if key in ['required', 'initial', 'min_value', 'max_value']}
    return forms.FloatField(**options)

  def create_boolean_field(self):
    return forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('True', 'True'), ('False', 'False')])

  def create_date_field(self, property_info, options:dict):
    """
    Create a date field with the given property information and options.
    """
    options = {key: value for key, value in options.items() if key in ['required']}

    if property_info.get('format') == 'date-time':
      return forms.DateTimeField(**options, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'datepicker',
        'type': 'datetime-local'  # HTML5 datetime input
      }))
    else:
      return forms.DateField(**options, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'datepicker',
        'type': 'date'  
      }))

  def handle_anyof_structure(self, anyof_options):
    """
    If 'anyOf' is in property_info, use this func. Property is generated by fields with input Union[[type1, type2]] or Optional[type1]
    """
    type_priority = ['date-time', 'string', 'number'] 
    constraints = {}
    field_type = None
    is_nullable = any('null' in option.get('type', '') for option in anyof_options)

    for option in anyof_options:
      option_type, option_format = option.get('type'), option.get('format', None)
      
      # if format is date but type string, update type to date
      if option_type == 'string' and option_format == 'date-time':
        field_type = 'date-time'
        break
      elif option_type in type_priority:
        field_type = option_type
        break

    for option in anyof_options:
      if option.get('type') != 'null':
        # Extract constraints like 'minimum', 'maximum', 'minLength', and 'maxLength' (from pydantic anyOf)
        constraints.update({
          'min_length': option.get('minLength'),
          'max_length': option.get('maxLength'),
          'min_value': option.get('minimum'),
          'max_value': option.get('maximum')
        })

    return field_type, is_nullable, constraints
```

```
class PydanticBase(BaseModel):
  date: Optional[Union[datetime, str]] = Field(None) 
  description: Optional[str]= Field(None, max_length=1600)
    
class Oil(PydanticBase):
  sector: str = Field(default='energy')
  fuel_state: Optional[str] = Field(default='liquid')
  fuel_type: Optional[str] = Field(default='Diesel')
  fuel_use: Optional[float] = Field(None, ge=0)
  fuel_unit: Optional[str] = Field(default='litre')
  fuel_spend: Optional[float] = Field(None, ge=0)
  currency: Optional[str] = Field(default='USD')
```

```
options ={
  'fuel_type': ['Diesel', 'Petrol', 'Gas']
}
form = PydanticForm(schema=Oil.model_json_schema(), options=options)
```

```
print(form.as_p())
<p>
    <label for="id_date">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_date">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_description">Description:</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" maxlength="1600" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_description">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_sector">Sector:</label>
    <input type="text" name="sector" value="energy" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_sector">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fuel_state">Fuel state:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fuel_state" value="liquid" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_fuel_state">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fuel_type">Fuel type:</label>
    <select name="fuel_type" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_fuel_type">
  <option value="Diesel" selected>Diesel</option>

  <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>

  <option value="Gas">Gas</option>

</select>
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fuel_use">Fuel use:</label>
    <input type="number" name="fuel_use" min="0" step="any" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_fuel_use">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fuel_unit">Fuel unit:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fuel_unit" value="litre" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_fuel_unit">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_fuel_spend">Fuel spend:</label>
    <input type="number" name="fuel_spend" min="0" step="any" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_fuel_spend">
    
    
  </p>

  
  <p>
    <label for="id_currency">Currency:</label>
    <input type="text" name="currency" value="USD" class="form-control rounded-0" id="id_currency">
    
    
      
    
  </p>
```

I havent tested it out for all possible edge cases that comes with Pydantic models, but it has covered most of the models with complicated rules I've been using.

I believe this is not a perfect function and possibly contains some redundant rules (Django fields are hard to inspect!). Appreciate any suggestions or modifications that makes this more scalable.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a templating engine. A very popular one is [Jinja](https://You%20are%20looking%20for%20a%20templating%20engine.%20A%20very%20popular%20one%20is%20Jinja).

There is also a whole chapter about [templating with Jinja](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) in the FastAPI docs.

This allows you the specify html templates that contain python like syntax to build what you want. You can pass in any data model and reference it inside the template.

Comment: OP is not looking for a template engine, they're looking for something to automagically generate and validate forms according to their pydantic models